# Registers, shl and binary in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

Im hoping someone can help me through a piece of code that I have as I find it difficult. Assembly language is new to me and I've been reading a book "Practical Malware Analysis" and I find it hard to fully understand.
This is what I understand of the code below:

13 is added onto var_C which is stored inside memory. 10 is added on top. 13+10 = 23 in binary that is 0001 0111. We shift left by 1 which gives us: 0010 1110 (46 in decimal). The last two lines above the conditional jump confuse me. And im not exactly sure I've gone through this correctly. But I can confirm that 46 was the answer I was looking for. However, can anyone confirm if my methods were correct? And what about the last two lines above the conditional jump?
Any help is appreciated

```
lea eax, [ebp+var_18]
mov [esp], eax
....
....
mov [ebp+var_C], 13
add [ebp+var_C], 10
shl [ebp+var_C], 1
mov eax, [ebp+var_18]
cmp eax, [ebp+var_C]
jnz short loc_4015F7
```

Comment: Just a note: `var_C` is set to 13, not added onto.

Comment: @atomsymbol Thats correct my mistake. Maybe you can answer to this. Why do we have ebp in front of var_C?

Comment: Because it's a local variable addressed relative to `ebp` which is presumably set up as frame pointer earlier in code not shown.

Comment: The last two lines have nothing to do with `shl`. They are a comparison and a conditional jump.

Comment: @RaymondChen What I meant was the last two lines above the conditional jump. I'm aware they have nothing to do with `shl`. The fact that we have `mov eax, [ebp+var_18]` after the `shl` is what confuses me. Is it correct that.... eax is set to the local variable of var_18. Then it is compared to var_C and if the result is true, the code ends. If not the code continues.. Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: It does `var_C = 13; var_C += 10; var_C <<= 1; if (var_18 != var_C) goto loc_4015F7;` PS: the code does not "end", if anything that is when it simply continues (goes on to the next instruction that you did not show).

Comment: The `mov` instruction is explained on page 73. "The format is `mov destination, source`. Operands surrounded by brackets are treated as memory references to data." Note however that chapter 4 is titled "crash course", so the book largely assumes you're familiar with x86 assembly language. You are expected to supplement the book information with an external reference.

Comment: I'm finally starting to understand little by little. And you're probably right @RaymondChen. We're using the book for a 4 week course on reverse engineering malware and I noticed its rough on beginners like me. Anyways thank you everyone.